# Completely disable CKEDITOR Parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, ckeditor

I have seen many many posts on this, but no real answers, surely there's a way I can disable the parser so that it doesn't reformat my content at all?

The only reason I want to do this, is because CKEDITOR doesn't yet support HTML5, so something as simple as a block element inside an anchor can completely ruin a template.

Inside the ckeditor.js core file, I've found the `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter` class. It looks like this is the main parser, I was wondering if someone could take a look at the source and see if there's a way to just return the static code before it formats it?

I haven't tried anything as I'm not really sure where to go. I've had a look but it seems a bit beyond me.

I've tried using the `config.protectedSource` option, and using `allowedContent = true`, however this doesn't solve all my issues so this is why I'm asking if someone can help me disable the parser.

If you parse html like this as a demo, and swap between `wysiwyg` and `source` mode, it should not format it at all.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/140/

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't try to do that. CKEditor's data processor makes content editable in `contenteditable` elements and without it you'll hit dozens of problems.

Native `contenteditable` is totally broken and this a reason why CKEditor has such complex data processor with parser, filters, transformations and thousands LOC that use them. This makes implementation of support for transitional elements (block/inline links) so hard.